# Why does a larger wire cross section mean less atom-electron collisions when there must be more atoms, too?

Tags: resistance

Regarding how resistance varies with diameter I've read this simple explanation on Quora:

> As electrons move across a wire, they constantly collide with atoms making up a wire. These collisions impede the flow of electrons and are what cause the wire to have resistance.Thus, if the diameter of the wire were larger, it would only make sense that the electrons don't collide as much, therefore creating less resistance due to a larger wire.

But doesn't a larger wire mean more atoms (I assume the number of atoms increases proportionally with the diameter of the wire?) meaning same amount of collisions ie. same resistance?

I don't question the fact that resistance decreases with diameter, but this explanation doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: The "density" of "collisions" is the same, it's just that "more electrons" are making it through. Many things are in quotes here as its a rather simplistic view.

Comment: A larger wire also means there is more total space for a given density of travelling electrons to pass through.

Comment: Keep in mind individual electrons have very little movement, actual propagation is mostly neighbor bumping neighbor; which while not an answer starts to suggest how abstracted from reality the model being contemplated is.

Comment: Actually, the number of atoms goes up with the **square** of the diameter. And the spacing between atoms is constant, regardless of the diameter. That's a much too simplistic explanation of the phenomenon of resistance.

Comment: @DKNguyen I can see why the OP is asking, and I don't think your comment helps to clarify. Suppose we try to move a single electron from one end to the other. Why does it take less energy if the wire has a diameter of 2cm rather than 1cm? Isn't the electron going to make the same number of collisions as it passes through the wire?

Comment: @PeterSmith Playing the devil's advocate here, suppose we want to move **just one** electron along a wire. Why does it take less energy if the wire is fatter? Won't the electron make the same number and type of collisions with the wire atoms? This question is making my brain hurt.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson It doesn't work with "single electron". "Single electron" is a wave function denoting the probability of the electron being in a specific place (or around it)  at the given time. The energy applied is just affecting this function. So theoretically there is a probability that the electron will stay in place. Or "move" without any energy applied. Statistically (with many electrons) it will converge to the Ohm's law

Comment: @EugeneSh. OK, assume we have enough electrons so that we can ignore their wave properties and call them, collectively, a "current". Let's say we have 1pA of current flowing, a very small current. Suppose we have a pure copper wire with an area of 1m\$^2\$ and some length \$L\$, and we need voltage \$V_1\$ to make the current flow. Double \$L\$ and we need to double the voltage. Makes sense. But why is the required voltage cut in half if we double the **area** to 2m\$^2\$? I understand the EE definitions but the physics is still murky.

Comment: @EugeneSh. ...and if you want to tell me that I won't understand the physics I can accept that. However, the simplistic rationals that other commenters have offered just don't hold water for me.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson I am not sure, are you confused with the "classical" reasoning or the quantum one? I will not pretend I am an expert in quantum mechanics.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remember that the electron that pops out the end of the wire is not the same one that got pushed in at the far end. It's more like a tube filled with ball-bearings. Push one in at one end and another immediately pops out at the far end. While the speed of the *wave* along the wire (tube) is very high, the speed of the individual electrons (balls) is very low.

Current is given by the equation:

$$I = vAnq$$

Where:

- *I* = current (amps, A).
- *v* = drift velocity (m/s).
- *A* = cross-sectional area of the conductor (m<sup>2</sup>).
- *n* = charge density (m) This is the number of charge carriers that can move per m<sup>3</sup>. For copper this is 8.5 × 10<sup>28</sup> electrons/m<sup>3</sup>.
- *q* = charge on each charge carrier (coulombs, C) is −1.6 × 10<sup>−19</sup> C.

Rearranging this we can see that the velocity of the electrons is given by

$$ v = \frac {I}{Anq} $$

For **1 A** in a **2 mm diameter copper** conductor we get a drift velocity of 2.3 x 10<sup>-5</sup> m/s or **0.023 mm/s**.

If we double the diameter we quadruple the area and get a drift velocity of 0.006 mm/s.

> Thus, if the diameter of the wire were larger, it would only make sense that the electrons don't collide as much, therefore creating less resistance due to a larger wire.

This should now make a bit more sense. If each moving electron only has to travel 1/4 the distance in the larger conductor of our examples then it will have 1/4 the collisions.

Answer (score 1):

No, resistance is a function of cross sectional area and length, the equation is as follows:

\$ R = \rho\frac{l}{A}\$

where \$\rho\$ is the electrical resistivity of the material.

If the current is the same and we increase the material's cross sectional area, then the resistance must go down (doubling the area of a material is like adding two resistors in parallel) because per a unit area of the material there will be less current. (less current means less collisions per atom if you want to think of it on the quantum scale).

Comment: is there a missing comma after the first word?